# Python запуск функций в потоках

Tags: python

Есть список из 50 значений. Нужно запустить обработку каждых 10 значений в 5 отдельных потоках. Причём в каждую функцию помимо передачи 10 значений `item` нужно передать по 1 значению `combat`, которе берётся из файла (в файле 5 строк).

Как это сделать? Первое что пришло на ум — создать 5 функций, запускать потоки в зависимости от величины индекса `items` и передавать туда значения.

Я слабо понимаю в потоках, в глобальных переменных и передачи переменных в функции. Объясните пожалуйста как это можно сделать.

```
from threading import Thread
import io


items = ['id10010', 'nikolaevkos', 'id70406', 'id75157', 'id91704', 'id112841', 'fm1989', 'panarinn', 'sharoykin',
         'id180771', 'androshkin', 'volynin', 'che1988', 'id298523', 'id299778', 'legalise', 'dm001', 'evgehuu',
         'cherkas', 'inowyoung', 'id401309', 'pressplay', 'dmitryssh', 'id433779', 'id436076', 'id436998', 'yomananah',
         'id451619', 'serb1589', 'id460010', 'id465818', 'id496477', 'id512701', 'massak_1981', 'andreihardy',
         'mofo.pepper', 'id587481', 'alkrendelev', 'dima_vasenovich', 'yustas43', 'id664978', 'voldaev', 'kost1qq',
         'id691602', 'id691719', 'vsbukin', 'toxemia', 'id715914', 'id726424', 'id726613']
item = ""
file = io.open("power.txt")
for i in file.readlines():
#всего 5 значений
    combat = i

def main(item, combat):
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        if i < 10:
            th = Thread(target=foo_1)
            th.start()
        if i >  10 and i < 20:
            foo_2(item)
            th1 = Thread(target=foo_2)
            th.start()
            # и так 5 функций

def foo_1(item, combat):
    for i in items:
        print("foo_1", i, combat[0])

def foo_2(item, combat):
    for i in items:
        print("foo_2", i, combat[1])

#ещё 3 функции
main(item, combat)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
def main(item, combat):
    file = io.open("power.txt")
    combats = file.readlines() 
    for i in range(0, len(item), 10):
        th = Thread(target = foo, args = (item[i:i + 10], combats[int(i / 10)]))
        th.start()

def foo(item, combat):
    for i in item:
        print(i, combat)
```

`args` туда кладутся переменные которые будут передаваться в функцию `foo`

`item[i:i + 10]` мы берём срез

1. с первого до десятого
2. с десятого до двадцатого
3. и т.д.

`combats[int(i / 10)]` мы делим число `i` на десять и превращаем в `int`

1. `i` равен `0` делим на `10` получаем `0`
2. `i` равен `10` делим на `10` получаем `1`
3. и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это похоже на решение! Буду теперь разбираться. Не совсем понятно что такое "args = (item[i:i + 10]". args объясняет поткоу что начинать надо с 10го индекса i?  Не понимаю что такое "combats[int(i / 10)]" Это объяснить потоку что после каждых 10 i нужно передать следующее знаечние combat в новый поток?
Вот те потоки что в цикле запускаются, они одновременно запустятся с разными значениями, или поочердёно после выполнения каждой функции?